# Regression: Can I use as outcome variable a score that is the total score of all the predictor variables?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, multiple-regression, predictive-models

I have a data set of decathlon sports which contain the performance of each one of the ten individual sports and then the overall score which is the summation of each one of the individual sports.

Does it make sense to make  some models with different factors (for example one model with sprint sports, one with jump and one with strength sports) and the total points (overall performance) as their outcome variable to see which one predicts better overall score? My question is: can I use as outcome variable a score  that is the total score of all the predictor variables?

Comment: So each event is scored on some scale say from 0 to 10, then each event score is added up to form a total maximum of 100. Now you want to test which event - on its own - is best at predicting the final score?

Comment: What i want to do is use nine out of ten sports in my models. Each one of my 3 models will have three predictors(sports) and i want to investigate which one of the models contributes more in the overall score. Csn i use  multiple linear regression for that?

Comment: Why 3 models? Why does each model have 3 variables? Is your end goal to predict the total final score as accurately as possible as soon as possible - using as few events as possible?

Comment: Every model represents something different. So one model has sports that involve throwing movements, one with jumping movements and one with only sprinting movements. I want to see if being good in one of these can predict better the overall performance.

Comment: In that case you can do that, build 3 different models and test which better fits the data - has better predictions. You choose the model which makes the best predictions.

Comment: Thank you. In my case the models are non nested with completely different predictors which means i cannot use anova f test for the comparison. Which metric would you use for their comparison for this case?

Comment: I would use predictions to test for differences. Use a separate test set to make predictions and then use a measure such as MSE to test which model makes better predictions - has lower MSE. Or alternatively use Cross Validation if you cannot afford a test set.